# Add Multiple JSON Objects containing a single JSON Array of Strings each, inside a single JSON File using Java

Tags: java, json, io, filereader, filewriter

I'm working on a Java Project that involves a GUI using FXML and I'm currently stuck on the I/O part of the project which involves **writing Arrays containing Strings to a single JSON File**, I have used the JSON-Simple Maven Dependency from Google.

This is what I have currently done so far for the File Writing part:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @FXML
    public void submitCardio(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, ParseException {
        //set file variable with file path
        File file = new File(cardioFileName);
        //get text field user input from GUI
        String nameField = cardioNameField.getText();
        //get text field user input from GUI
        String durationField = cardioDurationField.getText();
        //declare and initialise Array
        String[] cardioArr = new String[2];
        //define array indexes
        cardioArr[0] = nameField;
        cardioArr[1] = durationField;
        //declare JSON Object
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        //declare JSON Array
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        //iterate over indexes of String array and adding strings to JSON array
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
             jsonArray.add(cardioArr[i]);
        }
        // Creating JSON Object with cardio key and containing the JSON Array
        jsonObject.put("cardio", jsonArray);
        
        /**
         * Try block which includes the code that appends to File (FileWriter)
         */
        try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(cardioFileName, true))){
            String jsonString = jsonObject.toJSONString();
            bw.append(jsonString);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        final String addFile = "/MainMenu.fxml";
        final Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(addFile));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Main Menu");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }
```

I have tried writing to the JSON File however there are **Syntax errors once I have added more than a single JSON Object**.

**Single** FileWriter Iteration output below:

[This is the Image of the JSON File containing a **Single** JSON Object (only one FileWriter iteration, **CORRECT Syntax**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4sxE.png)

**Two** FileWriter Iterations output below:

[This is the Image of the contents of the JSON File containing **Multiple JSON Objects containing a single Array of Strings Each**, (two FileWriter iterations, **WRONG Syntax**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr7sx.png)

I'd like to be able to add Multiple JSON Objects without resulting in wrong syntax in the JSON File, as of now **Single iteration of writing to file works correctly**, *however* multiple attempts to write JSON Object to file result in Syntax errors, **included below:**

[JSON Validator Results of **Multiple JSON Objects added upon Two Iterations of FileWriter**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vXCJ.png)

Any help will be appreciated, I'm still new at JSON and Java; for any further queries comment below.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72280690/gson-to-append-json-object-within-an-array-in-a-json-file-in-java/72281690#72281690) is a similar question

Comment: @BorisIvanov thanks a lot for the comment, I utilized some of the code from your answer and altered it slightly which fixed the error, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, Please put a label "This answer is useful" it helps others to find answers faster. Thanks

Comment: @BorisIvanov Sorry I'm still new to Stack Overflow, it says I can't mark a comment as helpful but only an answer.

Comment: I meant the answer in another post)